# pgf90 fortran record length must be specified

Tags: gcc, fortran, pgi

sorry for my english

im working on a custom code for my physics master thesis, 
codes compiled with fortran90, and no one worked on this codes over 10 years...

after installing required programs (such as gcc, gmp, mpc, mpfr, pgi, pvm3, tcl, zlib...) in code files, i made a "make" command, and after "make" ; a "runn" file appears...

first of all;
after make command, if "runn" file appears, is this a proof that installed programs (gcc, pgi...) works correctly?

second question:
after i commanded "./runn &>runnlog"
there is an error in runnlog file:

```
PGFIO-F-203/OPEN/unit=100/record length must be specified.
 File name = dirname.inp
 In source file tbmd.f, at line number 77
```

this is my tbmd.f ; line 77 and below:

```
 open(unit=100,file='dirname.inp',status='unknown',recl=specifier,
     +    form='formatted')  
        read(100,2030) dirdir,label
2030    format(9x,a13,1x,a80)
    close (100)
    finit='initiate.inp'
        open(unit=10,file='initiate.inp',status='unknown',
     +    form='formatted')
    read (10,*) iistep,n,utot,ebstot,kintot,
     +                energy,press,tempi,pure,pure2,ele_mu,trace,
     +                i2,i3

    if(iistep.eq.0) i=system('mkdir '//dirdir)
    i=system('cp *.inp  '//dirdir)
```

and also there is a dirname.inp file:

```
dirdir  =13x00300epsa0 Input Directory name  
=====================^=====================
```

my supervisor said that, when i can do it all correctly, after make command,  a "runn" file appears, and "runn" command create a folder that was specified in dirname.inp.(in this example, folder name is: 13x00300epsa0 ) and in this created folder appears some results output files.

my supervisor doesnt understand about linux and other programing languages. and i dont know how can i fix this error (record length must be specified)

Comment: Please add the corresponding code to the question itself, the link is not enough - the content their might get deleted. Then,your question would be meaningless.

Comment: corresponding code is bigger than allowed character lenght

Comment: Even if you are not a native englishman, you can start your sentences with a capital letter and finish them with a dot. It makes the post much easier to read.

Comment: Well, then perhaps you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should find the relevant piece of code and post it here, no-one is going to debug some very long program for you.

Comment: ok, i edited my question, thanks

Comment: In `recl=specifier`, how is `specifier` defined? Which value does it have?

Comment: That particular line looks in danger of going past column 72. (I did not actually count for you though) If that's the case add a continuation.  If you have many such issues it could be the code was previously compiled with an extended line length flag.